# Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, findbugs, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I'm trying to use checkstyle and findbugs by doing `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` but I have this error 
[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kgNr.jpg)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project default:my-project:jar:1.1: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

I do not have a tools.jar into my JDK (i have jdk-11.0.2).

I'm on it since 2H, please help :/

Comment: Add all errors _as text_ to the question. No images.

Comment: @Leon edit your question and add your error inside **code block** not as image

Comment: try to upgrade checkstyle-plugin version as this issue was resolved in higher versions

Comment: Oh, sorry, done !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## `tools.jar` removed from Java 9+

You're on [JDK 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11). No `tools.jar` found there.

[*JEP 220: Modular Run-Time Images*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) removed both `tools.jar` and `rt.jar` from the `lib` folder, as of [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_9).

> **Removed: rt.jar and tools.jar**
>
> The class and resource files previously stored in lib/rt.jar,
> lib/tools.jar, lib/dt.jar, and various other internal JAR files are
> now stored in a more efficient format in implementation-specific files
> in the lib directory. The format of these files is not specified and
> is subject to change without notice.

This change is part of adding the [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), a.k.a. [*Project Jigsaw*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/).

To upgrade *Checkstyle*, use later versions, such as:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>8.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Notice the inner `dependency` block.

Consult a Maven repo for versions of [*Apache Maven Checkstyle Plugin*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin) and of [*Checkstyle*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.puppycrawl.tools/checkstyle).

Comment: What should I do then ? :/

Comment: @Leon upgrade to a newer version of Checkstyle that doesn't use those JARs.

Comment: Do you have a clue where I can find one please ?

Comment: Thanks. I need to put this plugin block into the `<dependency>` right ?

Comment: @Leon look here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html You should already have that plugin declared

Comment: @Leon ohh awesome! Consider marking the answer as accepted (per community guideline) so others now the solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: Beware, you may need to update your checkstyle.xml. E.g. i moved LineLength from TreeWalker parent to Checker parent.