# com sun tools jar not found even if it exists in openjdk 11 lib folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, sun, openjdk-11

In my openjdk 11 lib folder i have placed tools.jar `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\lib\tools.jar`.

But while building project with `mvn install` command i get the following error

```
Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8 at specified path C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot/../l
ib/tools.jar
```

Where i am supposed to put my tools.jar? Not sure which folder the error is indicating with `/../` before `lib/tools.jar`.

N.B tools.jar file is copied from jdk 8 folder. I also tried downloading this jar and putting in open jdk lib folder although.

Answer (score 0):

Your on JDK 11, tools.jar was removed in JDK 9, these links provide further information and may help in offering a solution.

These links may be of some use:

- [Answers with useful troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375423/missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar)
- [JDK 11 causing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207885/could-not-find-artifact-com-suntoolsjar0/55207956#55207956ntoolsjar0/55207956#55207956)

Comment: Yes this jar is removed, that's why i copied it from jdk 8 folder to jdk 11 folder. My question is why system is saying tool.jar does not exist in lib folder even though it is there.