# How to build JDK7 pom.xml using JDK 11?

Tags: maven

I need to build this https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/ from sources in JDK 11 environment (Maven 3.8.1)
here is pom.xml
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/ha-api-3.1.12.pom
now I got the following error:

```
mvn install      
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-maven-plugin:2.0.5
        or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
        Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:2.0.5 at specified path /home/katya/java/../lib/tools.jar @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: hk2-jar @ line 32, column 16
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin[org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-maven-plugin].dependencies.dependency.systemPath'
          for com.sun:tools:jar refers to a non-existing file /home/katya/java/../lib/tools.jar.
          Please verify that you run Maven using a JDK and not just a JRE. @ line 161, column 37
```

Please tell me how to modify pom.xml to build in my environment? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish#building ?

Comment: Why do you want to build it from sources instead of taking it from MavenCentral?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207885/could-not-find-artifact-com-suntoolsjar0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:2.0.5 at specified path /home/katya/java/../lib/tools.jar`
```

and

```
com.sun:tools:jar refers to a non-existing file /home/katya/java/../lib/tools.jar.
Please verify that you run Maven using a JDK and not just a JRE.
```

give valuable hints.

There is no `.../lib/tools.jar` in a JRE and there's also no `.../lib/tools.jar` in JDK 9 onwards.