# How to call Java tools static methods from own Java code in JDK 16 and up

Tags: java

I call a Java compiler, jar and other Java tools from my code. However the code stopped working in JDK 16 and up with the following error:

> Unable to make public static void sun.tools.jar.Main.main(java.lang.String[]) accessible: module jdk.jartool does not "exports sun.tools.jar" to unnamed module @46d21ee0

How to make my code working again for JDK 16 and up?

Edit: Unfortunately, there is no straight example of the problem, but some points:

Calling a tool: https://github.com/drogatkin/TJWS2/blob/02f4489ceddf325649eb2ac08cb98d51884f15fb/1.x/bee.xml#L513

Implementation: https://github.com/drogatkin/7Bee/blob/1a4443f3315ed39c38190bc128573b4329a49538/src/java/org/bee/processor/Task.java#L161

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't think there's a suitable answer on that other question.  Would you consider re-opening this?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55207956/642706) on the original explains that `sun.tools.jar` was [removed as of Java 9](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220). The solution is to either (a) fall back to Java 8 or (b) update your libraries to newer versions that do not expect that particular JAR. Seems quite straight-forward to me. I do not see any benefit to having more Answers here rehashing the same points.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I edited that [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55207956/642706) to be even more obvious. This includes a heading to sum it up: *`tools.jar` removed from Java 9+*. I added more links for even more background info.

Comment: The question is "How to make my code working again for JDK 16 and up?", not "Why did this happen?" or "What other JDK can I use?".

Comment: @Basil Unlike in the duplicate you linked, the OP appears to have control over the code and so they have another, probably more appropriate option: Use the `ToolProvider` SPI, [as explained in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.jartool/module-summary.html) (link is for the `jar` tool, but also works for `javac` and others).

Comment: @Slaw & DawoodibnKareem Very well, I re-opened the question.

Comment: It will help a lot if you can create a small example that works with an older version of Java but breaks with JDK 16. See [mcve] for tips on creating an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it's your own code that invokes various tools programmatically (without forking a process). The `tools.jar` file was removed in Java 9, but it was refactored into modules. For example, the `jar` tool now resides in the [`jdk.jartool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.jartool/module-summary.html) module. These modules may or may not export the packages you were using before. However, there is an SPI you can use to invoke the tools. Here's the documentation from the `jdk.jartool` module:

> Defines tools for manipulating Java Archive (JAR) files, including the *jar* and *jarsigner* tools. This module also defines APIs for signing JAR files.
> This module provides the equivalent of command-line access to *jar* via the [`ToolProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/ToolProvider.html) SPI. Instances of the tool can be obtained by calling [`ToolProvider.findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/ToolProvider.html#findFirst(java.lang.String)) or the [service loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) with the name `"jar"`.

So if you wanted to programmatically invoke the `jar` tool, you'd do:

```java
ToolProvider jar = ToolProvider.findFirst("jar").orElseThrow();
// you can replace 'System.out' and 'System.err' as appropriate
int result = jar.run(System.out, System.err, /* the arguments */);
```

The "arguments" are the same as you'd pass to the tool when invoking it from the terminal.

And you can similarly do this for the other tools (e.g. `javac`, `javadoc`, etc.). Note there's also [`JavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and [`DocumentationTool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/DocumentationTool.html). Those APIs are more feature-rich, but only exist for the compiler and documentation tools.

Comment: I am trying to validate you solution and currently look how to obtain a proper SPI.